# Most efficient way to find list of element text Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a page with a list of cards with information.
The XPATHS of each cards are:

```
self.automatic_payments_cards_list = (By.XPATH , '//*[@id="page-inner"]/div/div/main/lseg-gateway-billing-payment-line-info')
```

I'm trying to get the text of a specific elements for every card in the page.

```
//*[@id="page-inner"]/div/div/main/lseg-gateway-billing-payment-line-info[1]/lseg-card/div/lseg-card-container/ng-transclude/div/div[4]/div/div[3]

//*[@id="page-inner"]/div/div/main/lseg-gateway-billing-payment-line-info[2]/lseg-card/div/lseg-card-container/ng-transclude/div/div[4]/div/div[3]

//*[@id="page-inner"]/div/div/main/lseg-gateway-billing-payment-line-info[3]/lseg-card/div/lseg-card-container/ng-transclude/div/div[4]/div/div[3]
```

I know that with this code i get all the text on each card

```
for i in range(len(self.driver.find_elements(*self.automatic_payments_cards_list))):
            print(self.driver.find_element(*self.automatic_payments_cards_list)[i].text)
```

But i don't want to get all the text on the cards, only the text on this specifics XPATHS

```
//*[@id="page-inner"]/div/div/main/lseg-gateway-billing-payment-line-info[**X**]**/lseg-card/div/lseg-card-container/ng-transclude/div/div[4]/div/div[3]**
```

Can you guys guide me in finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to actually achieve this is by using find element_by_xpath on the element.

```
all_card_els = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-inner"]/div/div/main/lseg-gateway-billing-payment-line-info')

for card_el in all_card_els:
    specific_el_within_card = card_el.find_element_by_xpath('.//lseg-card/div/lseg-card-container/ng-transclude/div/div[4]/div/div[3]')
```

The `.` at the starting of the xpath is essential to make sure that the search is within the selected el, without the `.` you will always end up getting the first el which matches this xpath on the page. You can now use `specific_el_within_card` however way you like inside the loop, or append it to an external list.

PS: You can access the text via `specific_el_within_card.text()` as you mentioned you wanted to extract info for each card.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple.:-) Transfer your xpath as dynamical string and pass it, like you do in a loop for e.g.

```
 parent_locator_String=string1+ iterator + string2
"//*[@id="page-inner"]/div/div/main/lseg-gateway-billing-payment-line-info["+i+"]/lseg-card/div/lseg-card-container/ng-transclude/div/div[4]/div/div[3]"
```